# Index in part of a column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

In oracle: I have a table rel with these columns (object_id1, object_id2) that relates pairs of objects in a system. The object_ids are varchars and the first 3 chars identifies the type of the object. E.g. users start with 001 and books start with 002 but there are many more types. Now I'd like to get all user-book pairs that are related in this table with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM rel WHERE rel.object_id1 LIKE '001%' AND rel.object_id2 LIKE '002%'
```

To do this I'd need a b-tree index index on the first three chars of object_id1 and on object_id2. Is it possible to have an index on part of a column, in this case the first 3 chars? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a function-based index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_rel_obj_id
   ON( substr( object_id1, 1, 3 ),
       substr( object_id2, 1, 3 ) );
```

But then your queries would need to use the same function calls

```
SELECT *
  FROM rel
 WHERE substr( rel.object_id1, 1, 3 ) = '001'
   AND substr( rel.object_id2, 1, 3 ) = '002'
```

Normally, you would create user-defined functions (i.e. get_object_type) that were marked as deterministic and would use those user-defined functions in both the index definition and the queries in order to ensure that someone doesn't inadvertently use a different construct in order to get the first three characters of a field which would prevent the function-based index from being used.

All that being said, having a column in a table where the first three characters represents some other data element is a violation of basic normalization.  You'd almost always be better off storing the first three characters in a separate column rather than trying to parse the composite column at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a function-based index.

Assuming:

```
SQL> create table t (a varchar(10));
Table created.
```

Then you can create an index on the first three chars of that column:

```
SQL> create index t_s on t(substr(a,0,3));
Index created.
```

It will be used if you use that exact same function in your queries:

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly;
SQL> select * from t where SUBSTR(a,0,3) = '001' ;

no rows selected


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2699450933

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |      |     1 |     7 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T    |     1 |     7 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN      | T_S  |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the physical schema to put the object type value in a separate column (most performant approach), you could create a function-based index on the substring using the SUBSTR function, something like:

`CREATE INDEX rel_idx_f01 ON rel (SUBSTR(object_id1, 1, 3));`

Obviously you would need one index for each of the object_id1 and object_id2 columns.